# Reducing bandwidth usage on chrome by limiting images downloading

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, images, bandwidth

I can disable Chrome image loading in Settings > Privacy > Content settings > Images > Do not show any images. Or in Firefox in Options > Content > Load images automatically.

I'm looking for an extension, plugin or method that would let me show images on certain pages (A button that load all images). Also, it would be nice to display already cached images.

Comment: are you happy when some sites are not ever loaded on your firefox..??like adzerk.net which loads unusual ads and flash

Comment: I don't really have an answer per se, but I can't comment yet... I've got two cents to add, Google (themselves yes) has also now brought out a plugin "Data Saver (Beta) that does pretty much the same compression as Chrome on Android. Which helps as well :) https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/data-saver-beta/pfmgfdlgomnbgkofeojodiodmgpgmkac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a Chrome solution you can select the option you found in options to disable to loading of images by default. From there you should be able to click on the little "page" icon (or fav icon if the site has one) to the left of the address bar. From there you can tell Chrome to "Always allow on this site" under the images section.

From my quick 30 second test it does also seem to allow for displaying of cached images, I had to force refresh to have it stop displaying images for me.